# Detecting high frequencies with WebAudio API on mobile

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

I'm working on a project that requires detecting frequencies around 18kHz using the WebAudio API on mobile. However, the frequency bins I get back never seem to be able to detect anything over around 10kHz, but I know my phone can detect higher frequencies by using other spectral analyzing apps. How can I solve this or work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you're using live input.  You need to disable all the automatic filtering; take a look at [How to disable Web-Audio analyzer filtering high frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306309/how-to-disable-web-audio-analyzer-filtering-high-frequencies/31321291#31321291).